# how to manage javascript/image dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have an existing maven-webapp which consists of different components which are used by another webapp also. Such a component is packaged as jar-file and can contain jsp tag-files.

Now i want to use a javascript library and some image resources in my tagfiles. 
How can i manage those dependencies ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [js-import-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/js-import-plugin/index.html).